# IIS URL Rewrite - Rewriting subfolders to query strings

Tags: url-rewriting, iis

I want to redirect any traffic on my website based on the following rule:

- `https://www.example.com/abc`  -> `https://www.example.com/test1.aspx?c=abc`
- `https://www.example.com/def`  -> `https://www.example.com/test1.aspx?c=def`

I would like the subfolder to pass a query string, I have tried the following code but sadly had no success:

```
<rule name="Reditect1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)test.com/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{R:2}" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/test1.aspx?c={C:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: maybe this answer can help you a little bit to get an idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799910/htaccess-rewrite-subdirectory-name-to-querystring-param

Comment: @JosipIvic: Thanks for the reference. This is what I based my initial rule upon. I was able to figure out a solution that I will put in the answers

Comment: please can you reverse that rewrite from query string to only domain and default file (example.com/index.asp?id=555&guid=dsfdsfsdfsd) to (example.com/index.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after more research and trial and error I was able to figure it out. Here is how I have it setup now.

```
 <rule name="Redirect1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{R:0}" pattern="^(?!\s*$).+$"/>
                <add input="{R:0}" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/test1.aspx?client={C:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
```

**NOTE**
The rule was setup at the site level and not the server level in IIS. Hence, the pattern matching ignored the domain name.

**`^(.*)test.com/(.*) - tried matching a test.com after the actual qualified domain name. So www.test.com/test.com/abc would satisfy the condition and not www.test.com/abc`**

**Explanation**

The rule matches any URL that comes in - Pattern (.*)

The first condition ensures that anything following the qualified domain name has at least one non-space character

The second condition ensures there are no special characters in the part that is being parsed. This was my requirement.